# A late bus/marshrutka/train from Tbilisi to Batumi

Tags: buses, night-transport, tbilisi, shared-taxis, batumi

#### Question

I want to leave Tbilisi in the late evening on December 21 and arrive in Batumi early on December 22, what options do I have?

#### What I've found so far

- According to [this question from 11 years ago](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5932/what-time-do-buses-and-or-marshrutkas-leave-from-tbilisi-for-batumi) there was a Marschrutka and a bus leaving from Station Square Metro for Batumi at midnight. Is this still the case? What are some good evening travel options?
- This [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/5934/2708) to the old question mentions an overnight train. However, the latest train I could find at [tre.ge](https://tre.ge/en) departs at 17:05. Where can I find this overnight train?

Answer (score 2):

Only answering the night train part:

The train website [offers a schedule](https://www.railway.ge/en/traffic-general-schedule/) which mentions a train from Tbilisi to Batumi departing at 00:30:

[image]

However, it also mentions a date on the right (you have to scroll horizontally on the website to see it). It seems to indicate that the train is in service *only* on those dates.
If you search for a train ticket from Tbilisi to Batumi on [one of those dates](https://tre.ge/en/search?leavingPlace=56014&enteringPlace=57151&leaveDate=30.12.2023&passengerCount=1&IsSsm=) the train does appear:

[image]